# Rails and Selenium: how to stop/pause execution of a test in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, bdd

I'm having a hard (but very interesting time) diving into Behavior Driven Development using Cucumber, RSpec, Selenium, and Rails.

I have my setup ready for testing with Selenium, and it's funny to watch Firefox pop up and run automatically through my scenarios. But one thing I'd like to do is pause or stop execution at a certain point, so I can inspect what Selenium sees at a certain point.

I know of the save_and_open_page command, but this only shows me plain HTML without formatting. So maybe there is a stop_execution method or something that stops Selenium **without** closing the browser?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Install [pry](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry), then put `binding.pry` in your test where you want it to pause.  When you're done, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or type `exit` in the REPL that gets opened to continue execution.

Comment: This works great for me except when I stick the binding.pry in a view. Any ideas how to pause executing in a view? I  know I shouldn't really need to do this but it can be really handy sometimes.

Answer (score 19):

or just:

```
 visit '/'
 sleep(inspection_time=5)
 visit '/dreamland'
```

Comment: "This can bite you two ways. First off you'll want to set the sleep time to long enough that it gives plenty of time to get the response. But that means that you'll spend a lot of time idly waiting for the response, thus slowing down your tests. The second bite is that, however long you sleep, sometimes it won't be enough. There will be some change in environment that will cause you to exceed the sleep - and you'll get false failure. As a result I strongly urge you to never use bare sleeps like this." from http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html

Comment: I would not recommend this for testing. It's for inspection only. Having something nasty like this will urge to remove it,  after inspection. Kind of a `p` for debugging or `console.log`

Answer (score 2):

All the answers need installing new gems or even setting a sleep which is not the best approach. You can put this line anywhere in you step:

```
ask "Continue?"
```

It will stop execution until you enter `y` (Yes)

So, for example it would look like this:

```
expect(page).to have_button('Submit')
ask "Continue?"
click_button('Submit')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Debugger** where you want to `stop/pause` the execution.

or

In Selenium IDE you can right click on the **commands line** and you can select **Set/Clear Start point** to `stop/pause` the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it working by installing ruby-debug19 (for Ruby 1.9.3), and then just setting a breakpoint somewhere in a Cucumber step.

http://rails.vandenabeele.com/blog/2011/12/21/installing-ruby-debug19-with-ruby-1-dot-9-3-on-rvm/

Another option is to use the Capybara-firebug gem which adds a "Then stop and let me debug" step which basically seems to do the same (I don't know whether it relies on the ruby-debug gems).

Answer (score 0):

try to use selenium.sleep(ms)
this will make the test execution wait for the specified amount of time

Comment: Thank you, this is a good hint, but in my ***_steps.rb selenium doesn't seem to be available:

`undefined local variable or method 'selenium' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x007ffc6a230d70> (NameError)`

Comment: oops.. use java. so in the code selenium.sleep(), selenium is the object name.. so u have to modify it accordingly :)

Comment: I tried it with `page.driver.sleep(5000)` but then I get `private method `sleep' called for #<Capybara::Selenium::Driver:0x007ff87a558960> (NoMethodError)`.

Comment: `undefined method 'pause' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x007f81baed2fe0> (NoMethodError)`...But in the RSpec Book is written I could use a selenium object, I see... It seems to be quite outdated already, it seems. But how is it done now?

Comment: If you're just going to pause, you can just use plain Ruby `sleep 5`. But if you insist on calling a private method you can always do `page.driver.send(:sleep, 5)` (but look out for [traps](https://github.com/fxn/i-told-you-it-was-private))